# How can I make a secure cloud programming platform?

Tags: cloud, codesandbox, replit

I am quite fascinated with replit. I want to know how can I make my own cloud programming platform with a complete security system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I did research all I could find was docker implementations.

Guess it's time I start learning more about docker and it's implementations.